cannot access directory owned by self
So, I've got an odd permissions issue that I don't understand, and searching for it is coming up dry.
I'm trying to access a directory at /plex over ssh. (Technically I'm trying to use rsync to move files in there. Since this simpler issue is also happening from bash, I'm asking about it first in case it fixes the rsync issue as well. X-Y problem and all that.)
I'm successfully logged into my server via ssh with the command ssh plex@<hostname>.
When I run id I get uid=6704(plex) gid=6704(plex) groups=6704(plex).
When I run ls -lan in /, I see drw-rw----   6 6704 6704  4096 Dec 15 05:35 plex as one of the entries.
So my expectation is that, since the directory has RW permissions for group and owner, and its group and owner match the group and user ids I'm using, I should be able to cd into that directory. The result I'm getting however is a permission denied error.
The question at hand is what comes next for troubleshooting.

You're missing the search (x) permission on it, so you can't do anything with any file in end, only read the contents of the directory.

@StéphaneChazelas ran sudo chmod 770 /plex which fixed it, confusingly. I've only ever seen the x permission in the context of files as the executable flag.
Thank you, though. never would've thought to (in my mind) give a folder execute permissions to be able to cd into it.

Also confirmed, this fixed the rsync issue I referenced as well. If you'd like to post this as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

think of it as the "execute/axcess" bit (if you'll pardon the abuse of language)

(The POSIX text seems to talk about "search permission", but IMO that's a bit off. There's really no system call for searching for something, the closest is listing everything and looking for a match yourself. And listing the contents of directory is controlled by the r bit.)
